# iOS ActiveMQ Stomp Client for Chat - Get Active User's List

Tags: java, ios, swift, activemq-classic, stomp

How to get a list of active users from ActiveMQ server,  for ActiveMQ client in iOS?

Code, I've used to create a client

```
let host = "10.10.10.10"
let port = 61613
let login = "admin"
let password = "admin"


//inital connection
func createClient() -> Void {
    let crvStompClient = CRVStompClient(host: host, port: UInt(port), login: login, passcode: password, delegate: self, autoconnect: true)
    crvStompClient?.connect()
}
```

Connection with ActiveMQ server is successful.

Here is list of all delegate methods, available with CRVStompClient iOS client lib.

```
// Delegates
 - (void)stompClient:(CRVStompClient *)stompService messageReceived:(NSString *)body withHeader:(NSDictionary *)messageHeader;

@optional
- (void)stompClientDidDisconnect:(CRVStompClient *)stompService;
- (void)stompClientWillDisconnect:(CRVStompClient *)stompService withError:(NSError*)error;
- (void)stompClientDidConnect:(CRVStompClient *)stompService;
- (void)serverDidSendReceipt:(CRVStompClient *)stompService withReceiptId:(NSString *)receiptId;
- (void)serverDidSendError:(CRVStompClient *)stompService withErrorMessage:(NSString *)description detailedErrorMessage:(NSString *) theMessage;
```

None of these are providing active users list. Now, how to get a list of active users (connected with) from ActiveMQ server?

(my source code is in Swift 3 and lib source code is available in Objective-C)